# How does Leafcount work?

Tags: memory, number-theory, arithmetic, challenge-community

I am curious about how LeafCount works because when I count the number of leaves in my solution to a Wolfram Challenge, I get a much smaller result than those listed on the leaderboard for Multiples of 3 and 5:
[image]
Solution warning: I will show the solution to Multiples of 3 and 5, although  it is a very simple application of two basic arithmetic operators from number theory

```
LeafCount[ThreeFive[n_Integer] /; n > 0 := Floor[n/15]]
LeafCount[Floor[n/15]]
```

I made sure to look at the Possible Issues section of the documentation center on Leaf Count.
Two factors that might be the reason for this discrepancy

- LeafCount is based on the FullForm of expressions:
- Unlike TreeForm, LeafCount takes into consideration the structure of expression heads

Comment: Take a look at ``ExpressionTree[ThreeFive ...]`` and ``ExpressionTree[Floor[n/15]]``. You can see that your definition of function gets evaluated (!) and returns "nothing" (or something like this, I am not sure), therefore only one leaf. Try with ``Hold``: ``LeafCount[Hold[ThreeFive[...] := ...]]``, which will give you 17 leafs (one of them being ``Hold`` itself).

Comment: Thank you it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a smaller leaf count than expected because the expression is evaluating before the leaves are counted. To get the leaf count of the unevaluated expression, used Unevaluated:

```
In[1]:= LeafCount[Unevaluated[ThreeFive[n_Integer] /; n > 0 := Floor[n/15]]]
                                         
Out[1]= 16
```

LeafCount does not [hold](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressions.html#24449007) its arguments, so `LeafCount[ThreeFive[...] := ...]` is equivalent to `LeafCount[Null]`:

```
In[2]:= FullForm[ThreeFive[n_Integer] /; n > 0 := Floor[n/15]]

Out[2]//FullForm= Null

In[3]:= LeafCount[ThreeFive[n_Integer] /; n > 0 := Floor[n/15]]

Out[3]= 1

In[4]:= LeafCount[Null]

Out[4]= 1
```

The first Possible Issue example is a red herring, `LeafCount[Sqrt[x]]` gives `LeafCount[Power[x, Rational[1, 2]]]` not because of `FullForm`, but because Sqrt evaluated. `LeafCount[Unevaluated[Sqrt[x]]]` gives `2` as expected.

For some atomic expressions (i.e. rational and complex numbers), LeafCount treats the atom as a compound expression according to its FullForm:

```
In[5]:= AtomQ[1/2]                                                                                                     
Out[5]= True

In[6]:= FullForm[1/2]                                                                                                  
Out[6]//FullForm= Rational[1, 2]

In[7]:= LeafCount[1/2]                                                                                                 
Out[7]= 3
```

That explains why `LeafCount[n/15]` gives `5` (`Times[Rational[1, 15], n]`) rather than `3` (`Times[1/15, n]`).

Setting the issue of FullForm aside, LeafCount gives the number of leaves in the tree of all subexpressions (including heads), not in the tree of heads (as used by TreeForm). These are the "Subexpressions" and "Heads" structures in ExpressionTree, respectively:

```
ExpressionTree[f[a[b]][c, d], "Subexpressions"]
```

[image: "Subexpressions" ExpressionTree]

```
ExpressionTree[f[a[b]][c, d], "Heads"]
```

[image: "Heads" ExpressionTree]

Currently, neither ExpressionTree or TreeForm directly give trees corresponding to the FullForm of rationals and complexes, but it can be done:

```
In[1]:= tree = ExpressionTree[n/15 + 2/3 I, "Atoms"]
```

[image: tree]

```
In[2]:= positions = TreePosition[tree, _Rational | _Complex, {-1}]

Out[2]= {{2}, {3, 2}}

In[3]:= SetAttributes[atomTree, HoldFirst];
atomTree[fullForm_] := ExpressionTree[Unevaluated[fullForm], "Atoms"]

In[5]:= rules = Map[
  pos |-> pos -> 
    TreeExtract[tree, pos, 
     leaf |-> 
      ToExpression[ToString[FullForm[TreeData[leaf]]], StandardForm, 
       atomTree]], positions]
```

[image: rules]

```
In[6]:= TreeReplacePart[tree, rules]
```

[image: TreeReplacePart]

```
In[7]:= Length[TreeLeaves[%]]

Out[7]= 11

In[8]:= LeafCount[n/15 + 2/3 I]

Out[8]= 11
```